# Changing Nvidia GPU fan speed through API

Tags: performance, gpu, nvidia

As the title says, i searched for a way to programmatically change fan speeds of Nvidia devices on windows, but all i found was [NVML](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml), which only allows for monitoring fan speeds, not setting them. Any advice on how to achieve this feat is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Considering that setting the fan speed to zero might destroy the card, I strongly assume there is no such API.

Comment: thanks for the comment. 3rd party programs such as "MSI Afterburner" do this though, and they have to access this feature somehow.

Comment: Well, MSI makes those cards. They don't need an API for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

nvapi can do it on windows, I believe: https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__gpucooler.html

> The GPU cooler APIs are used to get and set the fan level or equivalent cooler levels for various target devices associated with the GPU.

on linux, the closest solution I've found so far is nvidia-settings:

```
# first, must set coolbits with nvidia-xconfig
# read more here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks
$ nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus
$ nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4

$ nvidia-settings -a GPUFanControlState=1
$ nvidia-settings -a GPUTargetFanSpeed=70

# or for a single card:
$ nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1" -a "[fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed=70"
```